# aiogram на inline кнопку повесить url и обработчик для статистики

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Не пойму как повесить обработчик на кнопку с url
пробовал сие реализовать через callback - не сработало. Других вариантов не придумал

```
kb_info.add(InlineKeyboardButton( 'Купить билет', url=f"{pay_link_dict['link']}", callback_data = f'pay_link_dict[name]}') )
```

Answer (score 0):

Здесь не нужно ничего вешать, просто делаете колбек, который ловит колбек_дату.

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(
        InlineKeyboardButton("text", callback_data="prefix:data1"),
        InlineKeyboardButton("text", callback_data="prefix:data2"))
    await message.answer("text", reply_markup=markup)


@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith='prefix:')
async def calls__(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.answer()
    data = call.data.split(":")[1]
```

А еще юзать аргументы url и callback_data одновременно нельзя.

Comment: То что их нельзя использовать я оптыным путем понял. Есть ли решение? Мне нужно что бы пользователь перешел по ссылке, а я этот момент зафиксировал

Comment: Апи говорит что это невозможно. [ссылка](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton) `You must use exactly one of the optional fields.`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47545531/telegram-callback-data-for-link-buttons

Comment: вопрос по другому, есть ли команда которая переведет пользователя по ссылке, а эту команду уже поместить в callback?